# How do I fix style loading issues in my nextjs app?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a nextjs landing page and I am using tailwindcss in it, The problem is that when I run dev server the div gets misplaced and is visible at a different place than it actually is in the source code.
[image: Misplaced div]

Here is the source code for contact section:
[image]

Here is the index.js :
[image]

The Div with purple background is coded in Contact section but gets shown in Footer section .

When I comment Contact component line 111 in index.js and uncomment it it gets fixed , here :
[image]

But when I run dev server again or refresh it gets again misplaced .

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Did you check your console for errors??